# form validation works in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form below and validation

`html code`

```
<form name="rt_form" id="rt_form" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <input type="text" value="NAME" name="fname">
    <input type="text" value="EMAIL" name="femail">
    <input type="text" value="CONTACT NUMBER" name="fphone">
    <textarea name="fMESSAGE" cols="44" rows="8" id="MESSAGE">
</form>
```

`Javascript code`

```
function validate() {
alert("you have clicked");
    if (document.rt_form.fname.value.length < 1 || document.rt_form.fname.value == "NAME") {
        alert("Enter Name");
        return false;
    }

    else if (!/^\S+@\S+\.\w+$/.test(document.rt_form.femail.value)) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    } 

    else if (!/^\d+$/.test(document.rt_form.fphone.value)) {
        alert("Enter valid Number");
        return false;
    }

    else if (document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value.length < 1 || document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value="MESSAGE") {
        alert("Enter Message");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

When i run this code in chrome it works good and **when opened in firefox the validation is not working...**

even the alertbox is not showing when clicked in firefox.

Is there any thing to add compability or something.

Comment: do you see any errors in firefox..

Comment: @Sudhir `[14:02:56.772] invalid assignment left-hand side @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/GMf8C/1/show/:32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have error an error for message at if condition

`document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value="MESSAGE"`

change this to

`document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value=="MESSAGE"`

and this post should be closed

Answer (score 3):

While validating message in textbox you are using single '='.So, you are not able to validate in FF.

Once check the following live version of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GMf8C/

**NOTE:** Tested in FF8.0

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend correct the following two lines

```
Change this line
<textarea name="fMESSAGE" cols="44" rows="8" id="MESSAGE">

to 
<textarea name="fMESSAGE" cols="44" rows="8" id="MESSAGE"></textarea>

Then change the line

else if (document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value.length < 1 || document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value="MESSAGE")

to 

else if (document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value.length < 1 || document.rt_form.fMESSAGE.value=="MESSAGE")
```

hope this solves your problem